# Most general $2$ linear map $(\mathbb{C}^2)^2\to \mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Which is most general $2$ linear map
$$
\phi(v_1,v_2)=a(v_{1,1},v_{1,2},v_{2,1},v_{2,2})e_1
+b(v_{1,1},v_{1,2},v_{2,1},v_{2,2})e_2,
$$
where $v_1,v_2\in\mathbb{C}^2$, and $e_1,e_2$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$?
By applying linearity and using differentiation, I see that $a$ and $b$ can at most be linear in $v_{1,1},v_{1,2},v_{2,1},v_{2,2}$ separately
$$
\phi(v_1,v_2)=\sum_{i,j} v_{1,i}v_{2,i}\phi(e_i,e_j)
$$

> What are the most general expression for $a$ and $b$ for $\phi$ to be $2$-linear?

**EDIT 1.**  Example
$$
\phi(v_1,v_2)=v_1-2v_2,\\
\psi(v_1,v_2):=\phi(v_1,v_2)-\phi(v_2,v_1) =3v_1-3v_2\\
\psi\left(v_1,v_2\right)
=3(v_{1,1}v_{2,2}-v_{1,2}v_{2,1})\left(e_1 - e_2 \right)
=3\det\big(v_1;v_2\big)\left(e_1 - e_2 \right).
$$
in this example the coefficients are a product of the components

**EDIT 2.**

\begin{align*}
&\psi\left(v_1,v_2\right)
=\psi\left(v_{1,1}e_1+v_{1,2}e_2 , v_{2,1}e_1+v_{2,2}e_2 \right)\\
&=v_{1,1}v_{2,1}\psi\left(e_1 , e_1 \right)
+v_{1,1}v_{2,2}\psi\left(e_1 , e_2 \right)
+v_{1,2}v_{2,1}\psi\left(e_2 , e_1 \right)
+v_{1,2}v_{2,2}\psi\left(e_2 , e_2 \right)\\
&=(v_{1,1}v_{2,2}-v_{1,2}v_{2,1})\psi\left(e_1 , e_2 \right)
=3(v_{1,1}v_{2,2}-v_{1,2}v_{2,1})\left(e_1 - e_2 \right)\\
&=3\det\big(v_1;v_2\big)\left(e_1 - e_2 \right).
\end{align*}

$e_1=(1,0)^T$, $e_2=(0,1)^T$, $v_i=(v_{i,1},v_{i,2})^T$

Answer (score 1):

Any linear map between finite dimensional vector spaces can be expressed by *matrix multiplication* (from the left, if vectors are coordinated into columns).

In this case, $a$ and $b$ are linear maps $\Bbb C^4\to\Bbb C$, and by letting
$$a_{11}:=a(1,0,0,0),\ \ a_{12}:=a(0,1,0,0),\ \ a_{21}:=a(0,0,1,0),\ \ a_{22}:=a(0,0,0,1)$$
linearity ensures that
$$a(v_{11},\,v_{12},\,v_{21},\,v_{22})=v_{11}a_{11}+v_{12}a_{12}+v_{21}a_{21}+v_{22}a_{22}\,,$$
in other words, $a$ must be a *fixed linear combination* of its input coordinates.

Comment: I cann't understand. If you look at the example that I've added to my Q, isn't $\psi$ a (skew) linear functional?

Comment: Linear functional would mean to have codomain the base field $\Bbb C$. The maps $\phi$ and $\psi$ in the example are not functionals but linear maps. However, as such, they are still expressible the same way using their values on the standard basis of $(\Bbb C^2)^2$.

Comment: ok, I made a mistake writing functional instead of function in my comment. But what about my example? Is it wrong? It is quadratic in the coefficients (because $\psi$ is bilinear) a according to your last equation it can only be linear.

Comment: The first $\psi$ is linear, but the second is *not* (in particular they can't be equal), instead it is *bilinear*: linear when one of the arguments is fixed.

Comment: In my question I wrote 2 linear because in my book, Greub speaks of $p$-linear; 2 linear means bilinear. The main question now is why the two $\psi$'s are different; I edit my Q